# Output SQL Table to existing Excel file/ new worksheet in SSIS / C# in script task

Tags: export-to-excel, ssis-2017

Good day,

I had a request to create a SSIS package that would output an SQL table to an Excel file. I had no problem creating this.  However, the client came back asking that they wanted to be able to output the SQL table content to an existing Excel file in a new worksheet. If the worksheet does not exists in my following script, it is being created.  However, it just goes back in the loop and fail because now it exists.

Here is my code:

```
public void Main()
    {
        string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        try
        {
            //Declare Variables
            
            string ExcelFileName = Dts.Variables["$Package::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString();
            string FolderPath = Dts.Variables["$Package::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();
            string TableName = Dts.Variables["$Package::SQLTableName"].Value.ToString();
            string SchemaName = Dts.Variables["$Package::SQLTableSchema"].Value.ToString();
            string SheetName = Dts.Variables["$Package::SheetName"].Value.ToString();
            string lastChar = FolderPath.Substring(FolderPath.Length - 1);
            string currentTab;
            DataTable ExcelFileTabs;




            //Validate format of FolderPath
            if (lastChar != "\\")
            {
                FolderPath = FolderPath + "\\";
            }

            string FullExcelFilePath = FolderPath + ExcelFileName + ".xlsx";

            OleDbConnection Excel_OLE_Con = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand Excel_OLE_Cmd = new OleDbCommand();

            //Construct ConnectionString for Excel
            string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + FullExcelFilePath + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\"";

            
            //USE ADO.NET Connection from SSIS Package to get data from table
            SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
            myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["ADO_DBConnection"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
                            
            //Load Data into DataTable from SQL ServerTable
            // Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.
            string queryString = "SELECT * from " + SchemaName + "." + TableName;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, myADONETConnection);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            //Get Header Columns
            string TableColumns = "";

            // Get the Column List from Data Table so can create Excel Sheet with Header
            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    TableColumns += column + "],[";
                }
            }

            // Replace most right comma from Columnlist
            TableColumns = ("[" + TableColumns.Replace(",", " Text,").TrimEnd(','));
            TableColumns = TableColumns.Remove(TableColumns.Length - 2);            


            //Use OLE DB Connection and Create Excel Sheet
            Excel_OLE_Con.ConnectionString = connstring;
            Excel_OLE_Con.Open();
            Excel_OLE_Cmd.Connection = Excel_OLE_Con;

            // Verify if file exists
            if (File.Exists(FullExcelFilePath))
            {
                //Verify if the sheet exists
                foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                {
                    ExcelFileTabs = Excel_OLE_Con.GetSchema("Tables");
                    foreach (DataRow excelTable in ExcelFileTabs.Rows)
                    {
                        currentTab = excelTable["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        if (currentTab == SheetName)
                        {
                            // Create Log File for Errors
                            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["$Package::FolderPath"].Value.ToString() + "\\" + Dts.Variables["$Package::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString() + "_" + datetime + ".log"))
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine("The sheet " + SheetName + " that your are trying to create in  " + FullExcelFilePath + " already exists.");
                                sw.WriteLine("Please enter another sheet name or delete the Excel file and try again.");

                            }
                            Excel_OLE_Con.Close();
                            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Create the worksheet in the existing Excel file
                            Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = "Create table " + SheetName + " (" + TableColumns + ")";
                            Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = "Create table " + SheetName + " (" + TableColumns + ")";
                Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


            //Write Data to Excel Sheet from DataTable dynamically
            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                ExcelFileTabs = Excel_OLE_Con.GetSchema("Tables");
                foreach (DataRow excelTable in ExcelFileTabs.Rows)
                {
                    String sqlCommandInsert = "";
                    String sqlCommandValue = "";
                        foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in table.Columns)
                        {
                            sqlCommandValue += dataColumn + "],[";
                        }

                        sqlCommandValue = "[" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',');
                        sqlCommandValue = sqlCommandValue.Remove(sqlCommandValue.Length - 2);
                        sqlCommandInsert = "INSERT into " + SheetName + "(" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',') + ") VALUES(";

                        int columnCount = table.Columns.Count;
                        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                        {
                            string columnvalues = "";
                            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                            {
                                int index = table.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                                columnvalues += "'" + table.Rows[index].ItemArray[i] + "',";

                            }
                            columnvalues = columnvalues.TrimEnd(',');
                            var command = sqlCommandInsert + columnvalues + ")";
                            Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = command;
                            Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                        Excel_OLE_Con.Close();
                        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                    }
                }
            }
        
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            // Create Log File for Errors
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["$Package::FolderPath"].Value.ToString() + "\\" + Dts.Variables["$Package::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString() + "_" + datetime + ".log"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

            }
        }
    }
```

Can somebody please help me with this ? I am pretty new to C#, and English is not my primary language.  Please let me know if this is not clear enough.

Thanks in advance for you time :-)
Mylene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know when you are trying to find the solution way to fare when it is just in front of you ?

My code, before wanting to catch the error if the user was trying to add a worksheet that already exists, already was trowing an exception in those cases...

```
    public void Main()
    {
        string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        try
        {
            //Declare Variables
            
            string ExcelFileName = Dts.Variables["$Package::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString();
            string FolderPath = Dts.Variables["$Package::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();
            string TableName = Dts.Variables["$Package::SQLTableName"].Value.ToString();
            string SchemaName = Dts.Variables["$Package::SQLTableSchema"].Value.ToString();
            string SheetName = Dts.Variables["$Package::SheetName"].Value.ToString();
            ExcelFileName = ExcelFileName + "_" + datetime;
            string lastChar = FolderPath.Substring(FolderPath.Length - 1);

            

            //Validate format of FolderPath
            if (lastChar != "\\")
            {
                FolderPath = FolderPath + "\\";
            }


            OleDbConnection Excel_OLE_Con = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand Excel_OLE_Cmd = new OleDbCommand();

            //Construct ConnectionString for Excel
            string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + FolderPath + ExcelFileName
                + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\"";

            //USE ADO.NET Connection from SSIS Package to get data from table
            SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
            myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["ADO_DBConnection"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
                            
            //Load Data into DataTable from SQL ServerTable
            // Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.
            string queryString =  "SELECT * from " + SchemaName + "." + TableName;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, myADONETConnection);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);


            //Get Header Columns
            string TableColumns = "";

            // Get the Column List from Data Table so can create Excel Sheet with Header
            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    TableColumns += column + "],[";
                }
            }

            // Replace most right comma from Columnlist
            TableColumns = ("[" + TableColumns.Replace(",", " Text,").TrimEnd(','));
            TableColumns = TableColumns.Remove(TableColumns.Length - 2);
            
            //Use OLE DB Connection and Create Excel Sheet
            Excel_OLE_Con.ConnectionString = connstring;
            Excel_OLE_Con.Open();
            Excel_OLE_Cmd.Connection = Excel_OLE_Con;
            Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = "Create table " + SheetName + " (" + TableColumns + ")";
            Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            //Write Data to Excel Sheet from DataTable dynamically
            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                String sqlCommandInsert = "";
                String sqlCommandValue = "";
                foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in table.Columns)
                {
                    sqlCommandValue += dataColumn + "],[";
                }

                sqlCommandValue = "[" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',');
                sqlCommandValue = sqlCommandValue.Remove(sqlCommandValue.Length - 2);
                sqlCommandInsert = "INSERT into " + SheetName + "(" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',') + ") VALUES(";

                int columnCount = table.Columns.Count;
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    string columnvalues = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                    {
                        int index = table.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                        columnvalues += "'" + table.Rows[index].ItemArray[i] + "',";

                    }
                    columnvalues = columnvalues.TrimEnd(',');
                    var command = sqlCommandInsert + columnvalues + ")";
                    Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = command;
                    Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }
            Excel_OLE_Con.Close();
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            // Create Log File for Errors
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["$Package::FolderPath"].Value.ToString() + "\\" + Dts.Variables["$Package::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString() + datetime + ".log"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Error log :
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Table 'Test9' already exists.
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at ST_a21007570143466693913591932c30b7.ScriptMain.Main()

Problem resolved.

Comment: **1.** What programming language are you using?
C#?
**2.** What is it?
`...Dts.Variables["$Package::ExcelFileName"]...` , `...Dts.Variables["$Package::Folder Path"]...`, `...Dts.Variables["$Package::SQLTableName"]...`, `...Dts.Variables["$Package::SQLTableSchema"]...` , `...Dts.Variables["$Package::SheetName"]...`
**3.** Your code now performs `sqlCommand Insert`?
I can't execute 'SqlCommand Insert`